# Sets, subsets, union, intersection, disjoint, and symmetric difference (Discrete Math)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

### Question

How are these two equivalent ?

> $A ∩ B = \emptyset \iff A U B = A Δ B$

Some clarification of why $A U B = A Δ B$? and why they are equivalent with be helpful.

Comment: I understand that A intersection B means two separate sets that do not share anything. And A union B means two sets that share each other elements, but why does it equal A delta B ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A \Delta B = (A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)$ by their definitions.

So $A \Delta B = A \cup B$ iff $A \cap B = \emptyset$ (if the intersection is empty we get equality from the above, if not, any $x \in A \cap B$ would witness the inequality as $x \in A \cup B$, but $x \notin A \Delta B$).

Comment: Oh I see now. They are equivalent when sets A and B are disjoint. I thought it meant A union B equals A delta B which was confusing at first, but now I understand it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$A \Delta B$ is the *symmetric difference*: the set of points in one or the other but not both.

Hint: When $A$ and $B$ are disjoint ...

Comment: Yes, you are right, because symmetric difference is like two circles that share a middle point in between, but its not colored, only the two different sets are colored. Similarly, disjoint sets are two separate colorful sets that do not share any elements from each other sets. That is why they are equivalent.

Comment: Could you please clarify why A U B = A Δ B ? Their venn diagrams are different from each other.

Comment: Are their Venn diagrams different when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint? That's the whole point of the question.

Comment: No I mean why A U B = A Δ B ?  on the right side of the logical equivalence.

Comment: Well if the right side is true you should be able to say something about the left side. I see that you've accepted the answer, so I presume you now understand it.

Comment: I understand the logical equivalence, but if you take a look at the venn diagrams for A U B and A Δ B, they are not the same. I don't know why they equal to each other. If you could clarify that more, it would be great.

Comment: But they ARE the same precisely when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint. That's what the $< = >$ means. I don't think I can clarify more than that.

Comment: You are still focusing on when A and B are disjoint. And I was talking about why A union B equals A delta B, but I got the main idea. Thanks.

Comment: I focussed on that because your question does ...